# "Environment publications undefined" - please help

Tags: errors, environments, undefined

[image: image 1 shows the environment "publications" undefined error in .tex file]

```
%Section: Publications
\sectionTitle{Publications}{\faLeanpub}
\begin{publications}
    \publications
    {\textbf{Contrails Whitepaper}}  {\textbf{Mar 2023}} \\*
    {\website{https://www.flipsnack.com/Atkinscontent/contrails-whitepaper/full-view.html}\\*{https://www.flipsnack.com/Atkinscontent/contrails-whitepaper/full-view.html}} \\*
    {I was the Lead Author on a Thought Leadership piece for AtkinsRéalis’ Future of Flight Market Growth campaign. I researched areas surrounding traditional contrail development; effect of Sustainable Aviation Fuels (SAFs) and Hydrogen propulsion on contrail formation; and how the wider aviation sector can contribute to mitigate the impact of contrails on the environment.}       
    \publications
    {\textbf{CAP2522 - Future Flight Aircraft Capabilities}} \hspace{10mm}{\textbf{Dec 2022}} \\*
    {\website{https://www.caa.co.uk/our-work/publications/documents/content/cap2522/}{CAP2522}} \\*
    {I am a named author on the UK CAA publication CAP2522 – Future Flight Aircraft Capabilities paper produced by AtkinsRéalis for the UKRI. The study aims to provide a comprehensive basis of Future Flight Aircraft characteristics which identifies novel features compared to conventional reference aircraft.}
\end{publications}
```

[image: image 2 shows that the environment "publications" is defined in the .cls file]

```
% Define the 'publications' environment
\newenvironment{publications}{%
  \begin{longtable}{1}
}{%
  \end{longtable}


% Define the 'project' entry in the 'publications' environment
% Usage:
% \project
%   {<Project name>}{<dates>}
%   {<Project description>}

\newcommand\publications[4] 
{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 1.5em}
    \textbf{\textsc{#1}}  \hfill \textsc{#2}\smallskip\\
    #3\smallskip\\      #4\smallskip\\
  \end{minipage}
  \\*
}
```

Please help...

Comment: 1. What Overleaf marks as “dubious” isn't necessarily an error. 2. It's certainly an error to have `\newenvironment{publications}` and also `\newcommand\publications`. 3. `\begin{longtable}{1}` is wrong.

Comment: Welcome! 4. `\newenvironment{publications}{...}{...` without the closing brace/curly bracket is wrong. But please don't post images of code or errors. Just post the code or error as text. If you need further help, please complete your code to make a complete example we can compile to reproduce the problem.